# Access Azure Key Vault using Service-to-Service Access Token via REST

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am having trouble getting enough permission to access Azure Key Vault using my app ( and not via user login ).  Here is my setup:

I have a azure key vault setup:
[image: Key Vault Setup]

I have given my app called "KeyVault" every permission.

My app is registered with Azure Active Directory.  And I have give it permission to access the Key Vault:

[image: App registered with Azure Active Directory]
[image: App given permission to access Key Vault]

After all this, I try to get an Access Token using the following REST API:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<DOMAIN_ID>/oauth2/token
```

The client_id and resource are both the App ID of my registered app in Active Directory I showed earlier.  (  is this correct?  )

[image]

I do get an Access Token back, which I use to try to query a secret in my vault.  Unfortunately as you can see it return an 401 error, which is no permission.  What am I doing wrong?

[image: Querying the key vault]

The URL is from the "Secret Identifier" of the secret in the key vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The client_id and resource are both the App ID of my registered app in
>   Active Directory I showed earlier.

No, the resource id is not app id. As Rich said, the value is `https://vault.azure.net`.

I test it in my lab with Power Shell, the code should like below:

```
$TENANTID=""
$APPID=""
$PASSWORD=""
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://vault.azure.net"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

$url="https://shui.vault.azure.net/secrets/shui01/cea20d376aee4d25a2d714df19314c26?api-version=2016-10-01"

$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"

}

Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url  -Headers $Headers -Method GET
```

Note: If you want to get the API input information, you could use Azure Power Shell `-debug` to get it. For example:

[image]

Comment: I also use Postman to test it, it also works for me. This is test result. `token` https://imgur.com/a/RAqpe  . `result`https://imgur.com/a/S80mz

Answer (score 1):

When requesting the token from AAD you should set the resource to be:

https://vault.azure.net

That will ensure that the returned token is 'addressed' to Key Vault.

Comment: can you give more details on how to do this